# print highest value in dict with key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

My dict is like,

```
{'A':4,'B':10,'C':0,'D':87}
```

I want to find max value with its key and min value with its key.

Output will be like ,

max : 87 , key is D

min : 0  , key is C

I know how to get min and max values from dict. Is there is any way to get value and key in one statement?

```
max([i for i in dic.values()]) 
min([i for i in dic.values()])
```

Comment: Use a lambda expression

Comment: What about duplicate values?  Do you want both/all keys?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could use use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
maximum = max(mydict, key=mydict.get)  # Just use 'min' instead of 'max' for minimum.
print(maximum, mydict[maximum])
# D 87
```

Comment: i dont think it will work,

Comment: @hackaholic Do explain why, I'd love to know.

Comment: what if D has lowe value than A and C

Comment: @Hackaholic Then that value wouldn't be returned... the whole point is to return the keys with the highest and lowest value.

Comment: You could also do `key, value = max(mydict.iteritems(), key = lambda p: p[1])`, since the question specifically mentions getting the key and value together. But it's rarely worth typing more code just to save dictionary lookups.

Comment: Make sure your values are numbers and not strings or you will get wrong answers.

Answer (score 14):

The clue is to work with the dict's items (*i.e.* key-value pair tuples). Then by using the second element of the item as the `max` key (as opposed to the `dict` key) you can easily extract the highest value and its associated key.

```
 mydict = {'A':4,'B':10,'C':0,'D':87}
>>> max(mydict.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])
('D', 87)
>>> min(mydict.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])
('C', 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

just :

```
 mydict = {'A':4,'B':10,'C':0,'D':87}
 max(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the specifications of the question. It is supposed to find the key with the highest value; not the greatest key and the greatest value.